# how can I limit the count of returned objects from a related manager in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I have two models Category and Product

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                               db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,
                            unique=True,)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                      blank=True)



class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 related_name='products',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                               db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

the wanted behavior is to return all categories with and each category should include 10 products

I tried to return all categories without limiting the products returned objects then I used the slice filter in the templates, but I am not sure if this is efficient for big scale and I am not sure if Django will lazy-load the products.
right now the view is as follows

```py
def product_list(request):
    featured_products = Product.objects.filter(featured=True).all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    return render(request,
                  template_name='home/home.html',
                  context={'categories': categories,
                           'featured_products': featured_products})
```

is the way I am using is efficient or I should limit the products when querying the categories using `Category.objects.all()`?

Comment: Can you share relevant parts of your models?

Comment: Also, it'd be good if you can share how you tried that, I mean, your `views.py`

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's an usual approach. Django's querysets are lazy and database won't be accessed until you slice the result in your template and that slicing would go - kind of - to the level of database.

Comment: thank you, I expected that because I did not find a way to perform the query limit to the related manager.